# Tomcat home page is not coming properly

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

After installing Apache tomcat8 I am getting below home page.

[image]

I just installed tomcat8, start service and hit url

`http://localhost:8080/`

I haven't created any project.

[image]

Comment: the picture isn't full

Comment: have you started tomcat yet ?

Comment: I just installed tomcat8, start tomcat service and hit url

http://localhost:8080/

I haven't created any project.

Comment: Can you stop your tomcat (or ctrl+c in that black window) and in another command prompt run the command netstat -na. Please put a print screen up here.

Comment: What is that Oracle page you have open in your browser in your second screenshot?  Do you by any chance have Oracle XE installed?  If so, perhaps Oracle XE is running APEX on port 8080.  Have you tried using a different port for Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me that the page in your screenshot is being served up by Oracle Application Express (APEX), not Tomcat.

APEX typically uses port 8080, and if you started this before starting Tomcat, Tomcat will be unable to use port 8080.  To confirm that this is the case, take a look in your Tomcat stderr log file (it should be under `C:\Tomcat 8.0\logs` and have a name like `tomcat8-stderr.2014-09-21.log`). It will quite probably contain an exception whose stacktrace begins as follows:

```
21-Sep-2014 12:09:15.607 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

I would recommend that you change Tomcat to use another port.  To do this, open your `server.xml` file (in `C:\Tomcat 8.0\conf\`).  There should be a `Connector` element in here with an attribute `port="8080"`: change this port number to 8081 (say) and restart Tomcat.

Comment: Looks like you checked my machine and then gave answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this

1- Download a tomcat version.

2- unzip it in a folder. (let say C:\Java)

3- open a command prompt window

4- Type C:\Java\ *your tomcat installation* \bin\startup.bat

5- Access `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not started tomcat yet.

Are you sure you have followed a guide like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20593_01/doc.560/e23613/app_tomcat.htm) ?